# How to insert a php code snippet in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

**I have a php code snippet like below :**

```
function is_ancestor_of( $page_name = null, $post ) {

if(is_null($page_name))
return false;

// does it have a parent?
if (!isset( $post->post_parent ) OR $post->post_parent <= 0 )
return false;

//Get parent page
$parent = wp_get_single_post($post->post_parent);

 if ( $parent->post_name == $page_name ){
echo $parent->post_name.' - '.$page_name;
return true;
} else {
is_ancestor_of( $page_name, $parent );
}
}
```

I just want to insert this whole code in mysql database table and again retriew it with this same formatting on the page again. When I simply insert this code in database using INSERT INTO query then the mysql syntax error occurs because the code breaks sql query because of special characters. Is there any way to do this??

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. Are you using prepared statements like in PDO? 2. Is this code you're trying to insert being treated as a string? 3. What is the column's data type (where you're trying to insert this code snippet; should be inserting into text types or similar)? 4. I won't ask why you're trying to add the code snippet to a DB row. I'll just assume it's a legitimate reason like a blog posting code examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this. Multiple ways:

1. PDO - that's the best option actually. Study this topic in the PHP manual as this can be a lot more help than just protecting your MySQL queries in PHP from breaking.
2. addslashes() - adds slashes to escape characters. This won't break your MySQL query for sure.
3. mysql_real_escape_string()
4. mysql_escape_string()

**EDITED**
Emphasized PDO as compared to the previous version of this answer as PDO is far more safer than the other options and there is a lot more to it which can be used while working with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Do _not_ use `addslashes` to escape strings for MySQL queries. You shouldn't even be using `mysql_real_escape_string` or any of the `mysql` module functions at this point. Use either `mysqli` or `pdo`. But definitely don't use `addslashes`.

Comment: Yeah, I use PDO myself but those are the ones that I started off with. But yes, definitely PDO should be the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Escape special characters using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). You'd probaply be better off moving away from mysql_* functions though and start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for example.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments, make sure you place the code as a string and that the DB field is the correct data type. Also, make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string() (if you insist on using mysql_*) on the whole string (or code).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape the php code so it does not throw an error when inserting. Then you run an eval() on the statement, if you want it to execute. If you have a mixed html and php stored in the database you would call eval like so

```
 eval('?>'.$dbresult.'<?php');
```

Just make sure you stripslashes() on the database result

Comment: yeah it sucks but one of the only ways to get code to execute from a db