# html special characters source code

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting into my database code that looks like this.

```
<h2>Hello</h2> &lt;?php echo "foo";?&gt;
```

How can I prevent the code from executing as a header 2 and changing to

```
<?php echo 'foo';?>
```

Is there a way to execute the code and disable the code on command? (I'll need to be able to get the source code so a user can edit what they have written)

Answers or links to answers or even hints where to find answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494415/how-to-insert-a-php-code-snippet-in-mysql-database)

When I am doing that, I use the PHP function mysql_escape_string().